# How to get the Firefox profile path dynamically in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firefox

```
data_path = "C:\\Users\\Cortex\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\5cfpvg5b.default"
```

Is there any way get this file path dynamically? Here,`5cfpvg5b.default` is not same for every computer.

Comment: the profile that is started by default can be found in `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` (on linux; i'm certain you'll find the corresponding file for windows...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`os.getenv()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html?highlight=os%20getenv#os.getenv) to obtain the Windows location of the `%APPDATA%` folder. The Mozilla folder is located under this. Then you could use Python's [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) to read the `profiles.ini` file in to determine which folder to use:

```
import configparser
import os

mozilla_profile = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), r'Mozilla\Firefox')
mozilla_profile_ini = os.path.join(mozilla_profile, r'profiles.ini')
profile = configparser.ConfigParser()
profile.read(mozilla_profile_ini)
data_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(mozilla_profile, profile.get('Profile0', 'Path')))
```

This would give you a path such as:

```
C:\Users\Cortex\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\5cfpvg5b.default
```

`os.path.normpath()` is used to ensure backslashes are used.

Comment: I got my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Martin Evans does not work, when you have multiple profiles, and switched the default one. Profile0 is the first created profile, but bot the default one.

So the last line should be replaced with:

```
for section in profile.sections():
    if section.startswith("Install"):
        data_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(mozilla_profile, profile.get(section, "Default")))
        break
```